# Vimeo API error 2969 after GET request using filter_tag

Tags: node.js, express, vimeo, vimeo-api

I have the following problem. We have a small web application using Express and the Vimeo SDK that fetches videos based on two tags. The process worked perfectly for months now, when suddenly we got this error today (still persisting):

Error: {"error":"Searching for a page that does not exist or is too far back in our catalog to present.","link":null,"developer_message":"The user's from + size exceeded 10,000, they requested a page of results that does not exist, or they issued an invalid query.","error_code":2969}

This is the query, the tags are an array of strings:

```
    vimeo.request(
        {
            method: "GET",
            path: `/me/videos?fields=uri,name,description,duration,created_time,modified_time,player_embed_url,tags,pictures.base_link,privacy,link,animated_thumbsets`,
            query: {
                filter_tag: tags,
                page: 1
                per_page: 20
            },
        }
```

We also tried this:

```
    vimeo.request(
        {
            method: "GET",
            path: `/me/videos?fields=uri,name,description,duration,created_time,modified_time,player_embed_url,tags,pictures.base_link,privacy,link,animated_thumbsets`,
            query: {
                filter_tag_all_of: tags,
                page: 1,
                per_page: 20
            },
        }
```

And this:

```
    vimeo.request(
        {
            method: "GET",
            path: `/me/videos`,
            query: {
                filter_tag: tags,
            },
        }
```

All with the same result.

There is no documentation on the error code, so I'm a bit at a loss here. Per developer documentation we should have 500 requests available per minute (way more than we need) and our account has around 3'000 videos in total.

Does anybody have experience with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for raising this matter, Vimeo development team already fixed this issue.

You can re-run your query and it will be good now.

Best,
Tamer

Comment: Thank you very much Tamer. It might help if there were more detailed descriptions of these error codes on de developer page.